# How to hand over a method call on a Master to n Workers and return?

Tags: java, multithreading

Let's assume we have n Workers which do some computation. The computation may take a while and n computations may run in parallel. Each Worker needs some data structure (not shared between Workers) to do the work.

I thought about setting up each Worker during some initialization of the Master and handing over the required data structure to the Worker's constructor.

```
public class Master {

  public Master() {
     // initialize n Workers and "register" them "somewhere"
  }

  public boolean doCompute(int someInput) throws NoIdleWorkerException {
     // check if there is an idle Worker, otherwise throw NoIdleWorkerException
     // call the idle Worker, hand over someInput and wait for the result
     // synchronously return the result
  } 
}
```

A Worker may implement Runnable and then be handed over to a Thread. An instance of Worker may be reused.

```
public class Worker implements Runnable {

  private SomeDataStructure ds;

  public Worker(SomeDataStructure ds) {
     this.ds = ds;
  }

  public void run() {
     // may call doCompute, but run() doesn't has a return type
  }

  public boolean doCompute(int someInput) {
     // do the computation an return
  } 
}
```

What is the best way to manage the Worker instances? I was thinking about using ThreadFactory which returns a Thread only if a Worker instance is idle, otherwise null. Using this approach, I would have to manage Worker instances in some data structure.

Also, since Master.doCompute(int someInput) has a return value but its computation is done by a Thread, thus asynchronously, I may have to use Futures. Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your Master has to do something with the results of all the workers for a given invocation, I would implement each worker as a Callable, with the work to be done implemented in its call function.

Then the master can generate its list of Callables from whatever you pass in and pass those to a ThreadPoolExecutor (which means you can control the number of threads actually in use for parallel processing of this kind) via the invokeAll method.

invokeAll returns a list of Futures, which will either have completed or have had a timeout expire (if you choose to set one). You can check if they have cancelled (timed out).

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection) for further details.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the feedback! The Master doesn't care about the results of ALL the workers, only ONE. So each computation by a Worker is run independently. In other words, the flow looks like this: Master.doCompute(), then look for some idle Worker, if yes, let the Worker run the computation, take the result and return Master.doCompute().

Comment: Ok, how does the master use the result of the computation by the worker? Does it give it back to some calling thread? If you only care about one worker at a time (for presumably a given call into the master), then instead of using invokeAll, create the Callable and call the submit() method of the ThreadPoolExecutor, which will return a Future. The key question though is what do you want to do with that Future?

Comment: If you want the thread calling Master to just wait for the result, then the easiest thing to do is after calling submit() on the ThreadPOolExecutor, which will return the Future (we'll call it f, for convenience), just return f.get(). The calling thread will block until the Future is complete or cancelled. If you also want to check if the task was cancelled, use f.isCancelled() and throw whatever exception is appropriate for your scenario.

Comment: Yes, the Master gives the result of the Worker back to a calling Thread. So your solution with implementing Callable, using submit() and then f.get() basically works. You proposed "create the Callable and call the submit()". I would like to pool n instances of Callable instead, each set up during initialization of the Master with some data structure. I don't want to create a Callable each time when the Master is called, simply reuse them. In case no Callable is idle, requests may be queued or rejected. The ThreadPoolExecutor only manages the number of threads, not the Runnables.

Comment: In that case, as well as the thread pool (which you'd want to do to manage throughput and for optimization) you could just create a stack of Callables which you push and pop. This stack can be bigger than the thread pool (so basically while there's a Callable available you would queue it, once your stack is empty you reject). The Master just has to maintain a stack of Callables, suggest you use an ArrayDeque for this. Assuming Master gets called from multiple threads, you'll need to synchronize access to the queue.

Comment: You can also use pollFirst as pop if you want to give the calling thread the opportunity to wait to see if a Callable is returned to the stack.

Comment: Thanks for getting this sorted out. I can see a possible solution here. But, in my case, the limiting factor is the number of Callables. So, if there is method call in Master and no Callable is idle, how would I queue the method call? I actually need some pool data structure i can initialize with a set of Callables. Are you aware of something like that? Of course, one could always implement it from scratch.